# How to get git-status of a single subfolder?

Tags: git

When I do git status in a subfolder of my repository it includes the status of parent folders also.

Is there a way to constrain git-status to just a particular folder?

Comment: no, "git status ." gives sibling folders as e.g. "../sibling"

Comment: Would you mind giving a little more context about why you want to filter out changes elsewhere in your tree? In what situations would you like to use this feature?

Comment: If there is more than a screenfull worth of output from the normal "git status" command

Comment: possible duplicate of [git status - is there a way to show changes only in a specific directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715321/git-status-is-there-a-way-to-show-changes-only-in-a-specific-directory)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
git status .
```

will show the status of the current directory and subdirectories.

For instance, given files (numbers) in this tree:

```
a/1
a/2
b/3
b/4
b/c/5
b/c/6
```

from subdirectory "b", `git status` shows new files in the whole tree:

```
% git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   ../a/1
#   new file:   ../a/2
#   new file:   3
#   new file:   4
#   new file:   c/5
#   new file:   c/6
#
```

but `git status .` just shows files in "b" and below.

```
% git status .
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   3
#   new file:   4
#   new file:   c/5
#   new file:   c/6
#
```

## Just this subdirectory, not below

`git status .` shows all files below "b" recursively. To show just the files in the "b" but not below, you need to pass a list of just the files (and not directories) to `git status`. This is a bit fiddly, depending on your shell.

#### Zsh

In zsh you can select ordinary files with the "glob qualifier" `(.)`. For example:

```
% git status *(.)
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   3
        new file:   4
```

#### Bash

Bash doesn't have glob qualifiers but you can use GNU `find` to select ordinary files and then pass them along to `git status` like so:

```
bash-3.2$ find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec git status {} +
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   3
        new file:   4
```

This uses `-maxdepth` which is a [GNU find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Directories) extension. [POSIX find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) doesn't have `-maxdepth`, but you can do this:

```
bash-3.2$ find . -path '*/*' -prune -type f -exec git status {} +
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   3
        new file:   4
```

Comment: Sorry took so long to come back to this answer - simple and correct!
I wonder if <pathspec> was added to git status subsequent to my question?

Comment: What if you are only interested in the current folder where `.` refers to but not its sub folders. Any work around for that? Thanks!

Comment: @benjaminz depends on your use -- for things like that I use shell globbing to select files but not sub-directories,  e.g. (for zsh) `git status *(.)`. Bash doesn't have a shorthand way of globbing only files, but you could use an extended `find` e.g. `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec git status {} +`. Seems like the sort of thing you'd want to put in an alias or script rather than type out all the time.

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to restrict `git status` to the current directory (without child folders) by giving a pathspec using the magic word `glob` and `*:`:

```sh
git status ':(glob)*'
```

Comment: This works great! Exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: Answer almost a decade later after the top rated answer was posted shows how a small snippet of how git CLI has evolved over time!

Comment: This even works on Windows - except that you have to use double-quotes (since cmd.exe is a massive pile of...): `git status ":(glob)*"`

Answer (score 7):

For me this worked:

```
git status -uall
```

Answer (score 4):

Imperfect, but this works as well from within the the directory you are interested in:

```
git status | grep -v ' \.\./'
```

That will hide all directories that would require an upward reference in their relative path.

If you want to get color spitting out the other end, set `color.status` to `always`:

```
git config color.status always
```

Comment: I love how grep always offers a makeshift solution if you don't know a more specific one.  Cheers to taco-bell programming.

Comment: This is way more powerful!

Comment: I prefer the clean solution but like the grep one too, it did not work for me with just \.\. so the extra characters helped.

Answer (score 3):

Some plumbing commands do take a directory as parameter:

```
git ls-files -t -o -m aDirectory
```

would give you all files changed but not updated (not added to stage), or untracked. And that for a directory.

As written in [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-05/msg01933.html), git ls-files does not support a '`--added` option.

> more fundamental reason is because `ls-files` plumbing is about the **index**.
>   Added is *not* about comparison between the index and the work tree.
>   It is between the HEAD commit and the index, and it does not belong to ls-files plumbing.

So, using commands [mentioned here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/97830/focus=99134):

```
git diff-index --name-only -B -R -M -C HEAD src
```

would give you both non-added and added files

```
git diff-files --name-only -B -R -M -C src
```

would give you only non-added files. (while detecting rewrites, renames, copies, ...)

As usual with plumbing commands, some scripting is in order ;)

Answer (score 2):

When I tried git, I didn't find a way to do that.

I ended up doing:

```
x@x:~/x$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       b
#       main/a
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

x@x:~/x$ git status | grep main
#       main/a
```

Comment: This is the method I was using... the following also gets the status headings:  git status |grep "main\|:\$" ... unfortunately you lose colouring.

Comment: Came across this question looking for a generic glob match. This is by far the easiest and works for me, e.g. `git status | grep ext` where ext is the extension. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

cd YOUR_REQUIRED_DIRECTORY , then,
 git status .

Comment: this will list subdirectories if you supply the '-u' untracked files option