# How to run "git status" and just get the filenames

Tags: git, version-control

How can I run "git status" and just get the filenames as opposed to the long relative path?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The output of `git status --porcelain`, designed to be easy to parse in a script, outputs the full paths rather than relative paths regardless of where your current directory is within the tree.

Each line output by `git status --porcelain` has two leading characters indicating the status of the file (e.g. whether it's untracked, modified, new, deleted, etc.) followed by a space, so if you just want the full paths of everything that would be mentioned in the output of `git status` you can do:

```
git status --porcelain | sed s/^...//
```

Comment: Same as git status -s but without coloring.

Comment: I found I was looking for a slightly different question, but this still includes the status marker (which I don't believe there is an option to remove). @sehe's answer is better if you purely want the filename and nothing else.

Comment: @IsaacAggrey: except that with sehe's answer you have to run multiple commands, and even those commands will miss untracked files that would appear in the output of git status, so it's not an accurate answer to the question.  It's easy to strip off the status characters from the start of the output produced by what I suggested - I've edited my answer to show how.

Comment: @earlonrails its only the same if you're at the root, run the same commands from a subdirectory of the repo and you'll see one uses relative paths to the working directory, the other full paths in the repo's root

Comment: @jxramos You can still use cut just change the flag for git status command, `git status --porcelain | cut -c4-`. IMO `cut` is better than using `sed` because more systems will have `cut` already installed.

Comment: Does not produce pathnames relative to current directory like [`git status | cut` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736749/4035845)

Answer (score 94):

I think `cut` is good for this.

```
git status -s | cut -c4-
```

Comment: and here I was using sed to strip the status codes.  never used the -c flag for cut before.  nice!  add this to your .gitconfig for a good daystarter: `de=!$EDITOR $( git status --porcelain | cut -c4- ) & # open all changed files in EDITOR`

Comment: For someone who are not familiar with `cut` command, `cut -c 4-` means, take characters from fourth character.

Comment: Yes, cleaner than sed in this case.

Answer (score 60):

Aha, I *think* I just **understood the question**: you want basenames? Tack on `| while read a; do basename "$a"; done` to any of the following:

how about

- `git diff --name-only`

  for changes relative to index
- `git diff --name-only --staged`

  for ... well staged chages :)
- `git diff --name-only HEAD`

  got both

Comment: I see, if you want just _basenames_ tack this on at the end of any:
` | while read fname; do basename "$fname"; done`

Comment: Does not produce pathnames relative to current directory like [git status | cut answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736749/4035845)

Comment: Even though it certainly only outputs relative to the root of the git repository, this is a much more to the point solution than `git status --porcelain`, since you don't need to process/clean up its output.

Comment: Works just great:  
`vi \`git dno\`` I believe the dno shortcut for git diff came in my gitconfig by default.

Answer (score 21):

A much simpler solution that is built-in to `git` using [`ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

From the docs:

> OPTIONS
>
> -c
>   --cached Show cached files in the output (default)
>
> -d
>   --deleted Show deleted files in the output
>
> -m
>   --modified Show modified files in the output
>
> -o
>   --others Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output
>
> -i
>   --ignored Show only ignored files in the output. When showing files in the index, print only those matched by an exclude pattern. When
>   showing "other" files, show only those matched by an exclude pattern.
>   Standard ignore rules are not automatically activated, therefore at
>   least one of the --exclude* options is required.
>
> -s
>   --stage Show staged contents' mode bits, object name and stage number in the output.
>
> -u
>   --unmerged Show unmerged files in the output (forces --stage)

Example showing flags can be combined as well:

```sh
git ls-files -dmo
```

Comment: Very nice. I used `git ls-files -m | grep pom.xml` after running `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.7:set` in my jenkins job. That way i don't have to know what all modules are in the project and worry about missing adding/committing them.

Answer (score 3):

`git status` will always walk down (**edit** and up) the tree and display relative paths.  If you only want the file in the directory you are in, [See this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715321/git-status-is-there-a-way-to-show-changes-only-in-a-specific-directory/715344#715344)

Answer (score 3):

Get the name of modified files

`git status --porcelain|awk '{if($1=="M") {print "basename " $2}}'|sh`

I use similar script to copy my modified files to a remote server, as below:

```
git status --porcelain|awk '{if($1=="M") {print "scp " $2 " account_name@server_ip:~/my_codebase/$(dirname " $2 ")/;"} }'|sh
```

Comment: There's an easier way to search using awk:

`git status --porcelain | awk '/^ M/{ print $2 }'`

Answer (score 3):

git status outputs relative paths so if you cd to the same directory as the file (under your working directory's root) before running git status it will only output the basenames of added/staged files.

```
cd /long/path/to/my/repo/root/dir
"stuff" > ./newfile.txt
> git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   /long/path/to/my/repo/root/dir/plus/some/more/levels/of/directory/structure/inside/it/changed_file.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#       long/path/to/my/repo/root/dir/plus/some/even/more/levels/of/directory/structure/inside/it/but_another_new_file.txt
#       newfile.txt
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

ie, 'newfile.txt' is listed without the full path because you're in the same path as it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, another way of doing it is with `awk`

```
git status --porcelain | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

The `$2` selects second the column of each line.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for only the filenames without the path mumbo-jumbo the following should work:

```
git status --porcelain | cut -c 3- | xargs basename -a
```

This script gets the shortened format of git status, cuts each line's 3rd column to the end and feeds it to the `basename` command which outputs only the filename from the full path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files), as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62478087/6309) by [Peter Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386924/peter-benjamin), know that, with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), its options have been clarified.

See [commit e750951](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e750951e74fc3fc2b40a8601b70cdf6e69ec6cf2), [commit 4173b80](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4173b806c75dbcf4406c7a5ad6158dcbfa2beb2f), [commit 2b02d2d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d), [commit 2a34b31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a34b3181dba0d2049dff127ee70aca0c255a7ad) (13 Jan 2023) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3eda830](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3eda8302e5db9116580b9589de50368694f6ceba), 03 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d): clarify descriptions of file selection options
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> The previous descriptions of the file selection options were very easy to misunderstand.
> For example:
>
> - "**Show cached files in the output**" This could be interpreted as meaning "show files which have been modified and git-add'ed, i.e.
>   files which have cached changes relative to HEAD".
> - "**Show deleted files**" This could be interpreted as meaning "for each [`git rm $FILE`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d/Documentation/git-rm.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm))</sup> we ran, show me `$FILE`"
> - "**Show modified files**" This could be interpreted as meaning "show files which have been modified and git-add'ed" or as "show me files that differ from HEAD" or as "show me undeleted files different from HEAD" (given that `--deleted` is a separate option), none of which are correct.
>
> Further, it's not very clear when some options only modify and/or override other options, as was the case with `--ignored`, `--directory`, and `--unmerged` (I've seen folks confused by each of them on the mailing list, sometimes even fellow Git developers.)
>
> Tweak these definitions, and the one for `--killed`, to try to make them all a bit more clear.
> Finally, also clarify early on that duplicate reports for paths are often expected (both when (a) there are multiple entries for the file in the index -- i.e.
> when there are conflicts, and also (b) when the user specifies options that might pick the same file multiple times, such as [`git` ls-files `--cached` --deleted --modified``](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L39)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---cached))</sup> when there is a file with an unstaged deletion).

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L40-L42):

> ### `--cached`:
>
> Show all files cached in Git's index, i.e. all tracked files.
> (This is the default if no `-c`/`-s`/`-d`/`-o`/`-u`/`-k`/`-m`/`--resolve-undo`
> options are specified.)

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L46):

> ### `--deleted`:
>
> Show files with an unstaged deletion

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L50-L51):

> ### `--modified`:
>
> Show files with an unstaged modification (note that an unstaged
> deletion also counts as an unstaged modification)

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L59-L66):

> ### `--ignored`
>
> Show only ignored files in the output.
> Must be used with
> either an explicit '`-c`' or '`-o`'.
>
> - When showing files in the
>   index (i.e. when used with '`-c`'), print only those files
>   matching an exclude pattern.
> - When showing "other" files
>   (i.e. when used with '`-o`'), show only those matched by an
>   exclude pattern.
>
> Standard ignore rules are not automatically
> activated, therefore at least one of the `--exclude*` options
> is required.

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L82-L84):

> ### `--unmerged`:
>
> Show information about unmerged files in the output, but do
> not show any other tracked files (forces `--stage`, overrides
> `--cached`).

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b02d2df2bc38048ca70c82024834995624c2f4d/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L88-L90):

> ### --killed
>
> Show untracked files on the filesystem that need to be removed
> due to file/directory conflicts for tracked files to be able to
> be written to the filesystem.

Comment: See also [commit bbc8c05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbc8c0567026499f235058b654863c7bda19eb9e) from 2.44:  If you are trying to emulate the way Porcelain commands work, using the `--exclude-standard` option instead is easier and thorougher than `--exclude-per-directory=<file>`. I illustrate that in "[Git command to show which specific files are ignored by `.gitignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467053/6309)"