# How to normalize working tree line endings in Git?

Tags: git, line-endings, gitattributes

I have cloned a repository that had inconsistend line endings. I have added a `.gitattributes` that sets the text attribute for the files I want to normalize. Now when I commit changes I get the message:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in FILE.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

How can I make git normalize my working copy of the file for me? Preferably I would like git to normalize the entire working tree.

Comment: For people coming to this question in 2019, note that the second answer (by @philippn) is now better than the currently accepted one

Answer (score 126, accepted):

With Git client 2.16 and higher there is now a much simpler way to do this. Just use:

```
git add --renormalize .
```

Note: it's better to do this with a clean workspace. For details, see:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion
- https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings

Comment: I just tried this on Git Bash for Windows and it staged every file in the repo for commit.

Comment: I have a error message: `error: unknown option 'renormalize'`

Comment: @RyanNghiem What does `git --version` say? I would guess it's simply older than 2.16 and you need to upgrade. HTH

Comment: @cja "Clean workspace" as in: the command `git status` returns something like `nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: This just doesn't do anything at all for me. :-/

Comment: Doesnt work. Downvote

Comment: @wilmol works like a charm for those who read the first 4 words of the answer and not just the copy paste the command. And it helps to have an up up to date version  of git.

Comment: This command does absolute nothing for me.

Answer (score 139):

For those using v2.16 or better, you can simply use:

```
git add --renormalize .  # Update index with renormalized files
git status               # Show the files that will be normalized
git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
```

These directions are straight out of the [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion).  For older versions, the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes/2.11.1#_end_of_line_conversion) 
(prior to v2.12) provide a different answer:

```
rm .git/index     # Remove the index to force git to
git reset         # re-scan the working directory
git status        # Show files that will be normalized
git add -u
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
```

Do this sequence after you have edited `.gitattributes`.

#### Update

It appears some users have had trouble with the above instructions.  Updated docs for [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes/2.14.3#_end_of_line_conversion) (2.12 to 2.14) shows a new set of instructions (after editing the .gitattributes files):

```
git read-tree --empty   # Clean index, force re-scan of working directory
git add .
git status        # Show files that will be normalized
git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
```

Thanks to [@vossad01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072626/vossad01) for pointing this out.

Also, with either solution the files in your working copy still retain their old line endings.  If you want to update them, make sure your **working tree is clean** and use:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

Now the line endings will be correct in your working tree.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I was looking through the gitattributes documentation but it was so much to read so I sort of glossed over it and couldn't find what I was looking for. I feel stupid now.

Comment: No worries, it happens!  It's not as easy to find as it probably should be. :-)

Comment: This works when adding `.gitattributes` for the first time or changing the setting, but it doesn't work if the working tree has a different EOL (at least with MsysGit it doesn't). For that, it appears that `git rm --cached -r .` and then `git reset --hard` worked (warning: destroys your working tree). From https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings.

Comment: Has something changed with Git that has broken this?  I have used this many times, but now am in a repository where it is not working (git 2.13.0, linux).  Instead I had to do `git add .` after removing the index (being mindful of anything in the working directory that was previously untracked).

Comment: @vossad01 Can you explain what failed in the process?  I don't see a reason why the current answer shouldn't work.  I can certainly update the answer with the new procedure too--I just want to understand the issue a little more.

Comment: @jszakmeister It does not normalize any files, see my previous comment about wondering if something changed with Git that broke it.  I don't know (and am not motivated enough to research) what changed, but I have now bounced between enough different environments to be confident something has changed causing new directions to be needed.

Comment: @vossad01 Interesting.  I guess I'm going to have to play with it more and see. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @vossad01 So I've tried both ways and the old way still works fine.  In fact, with both ways I end up with exactly the same results.  I don't know what you did, but the one requirement for `git add -u` to work is that the file must have been versioned already (it must be part of the repo).  So maybe that where things fail?  I tried this with 2.15.0, so it's possible there was some other bug affecting this for some short time too.

Comment: Only the second method worked for me. Came here as other guides all have the first method, which wasn't working, but git read-tree --empty method was the trick

Comment: Be cautious with the `git read-tree --empty; git add .` variant.  Any tracked files that would be ignored by .gitignore will be deleted when using it.  The documentation now recommends `git add --renormalize .`

Comment: Is there a setting I need to change somewhere? I have ran these commands multiple times now and it says succesfull in bash, but when I open the file in notepad++ with lineendings showing, it still shows CRLF.

Comment: @RogerFar what OS are you running on? Windows?  What does `git config --get core.autocrlf` say?

Comment: It says `false`. But even when it "tries" to convert line endings it too quick, like 5 seconds for 1000 files. In the end I used notepad++ to do a global search and replace.

Comment: @RogerFar Do you have a `.gitattributes` set up?  I've never seen this be a real problem, even under Windows.  It sounds like you've missed a step or there is something environmental going on.  And 5 seconds for 1,000 is quite possible.  The conversion is pretty darn easy, and Git is awfully efficient in what it does.  Sorry it was an issue for you though.

Comment: I did setup .gitattributes yeah, but it's strange. It did commit "something" but a git blame didn't show it changed line endings at all, neither did notepad++.

Answer (score 12):

### Alternative approach (differs only in command used)

Make sure you have no any pending changes in repository:

```
$ git status
$ git stash
```

Modify `.gitattributes` so CRLF interpretation will changed:

```
$ echo "*.txt  text" >>.gitattributes
$ git commit -m "Made .txt files a subject to CRLF normalization." -- .gitattributes
```

Remove data from index and refresh working directory:

```
$ git rm --cached -r .
$ git reset --hard
```

Review CRLF fixes that Git proposes:

```
$ git ls-files --eol
$ git status
$ git diff
```

Agree with Git decision:

```
$ git add -u
$ git commit -m "Normalized CRLF for .txt files"
```

Reload changes as if clean clone was done:

```
$ git rm --cached -r .
$ git reset --hard
```

Comment: Note: the `--eol` option to `git ls-files` is new in Git 2.8 (not that new any more, but some people are still suffering with Git 1.7, even late in 2018!).

Comment: `git ls-files --eol` helps verify that your line endings in all files are as intended, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `.gitattributes` settings will only affect new commits. If this repository has *no* history published (no others depending on it), you might want to go through the whole history. In Unix/Linux, you can use `dos2unix(1)` to fix all files in combination with `find(1)`, and using the history rewriting of `filter-branch` (see the [discussion](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) in the git book) you can even clean up the full history of the project.

Use with utmost care, on a fresh clone. Get in contact with *anybody* who might have a clone, and advise them what you want to do.

Comment: I would generally advise against this solution, unless a perfect history is important. There are so many ways to shoot oneself in the foot by rewriting the history. Normalize the files in the repo in a single commit, and let .gitattributes do the work from there on out.

Comment: @angularsen, if it is important to publish a clean, useable history... that is why I advise to work on a clean, new clone and (re)publish that once it is checked sane.

Answer (score 3):

I had to re-clone repo with this flag `-c core.autocrlf=false`, and it worked, no other config required.

Like this:

```
git clone -c core.autocrlf=false https://github.com/any-repo.git
```

Our project initially was made with LF on Mac, but on Windows it was automatically converted to CRLF. We use eslint and it underlined every line of code, until I re-cloned it.

Answer (score 2):

The * text=auto option in .gitattributes leaves the Git repository in an 'illegal state' if it contains files with CRLF (Windows) line endings which are now marked as text (see https://marc.info/?l=git&m=154484903528621&w=2). The standard renormalize option does not work correctly with the LFS filters, so the instructions in the other answers or for example at https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings, do not work correctly. Instead these steps worked for us:

Situation:

- On Windows
- Git repository contained files with both CR and CRLF line endings
- Added * text=auto to .gitattributes (so not depended on user having set    core.crlf=auto on Windows)
- Also changed the -crlf to -text for LFS tracked files, not sure that is needed.

  1. Create a new branch from the branch with the line ending problem (assuming no uncommitted changes there): git checkout -b feature/doing-stuff-fix-eol
  2. Remove the LFS filters from .gitattributes (replace all 'filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs ' with nothing)
  3. Commit and push: git commit -a -m "Disable LFS filters for EOL fix"
  4. Move to non-git folder
  5. Uninstall LFS globally: git lfs uninstall
  6. Create a new repository clone: git clone -b feature/doing-stuff-fix-eol [remote repository url] fix-eol
  7. Normalize the line endings: git add --renormalize . (note the dot to renormalize all files)
  8. Check only the correct files normalized. It should not include files normally handled by LFS!
  9. Commit and push (save the hash): git commit -m "Fix line endings"
  10. Move to non-git folder
  11. Install LFS globally: git lfs install
  12. Go to original repository clone and pull
  13. Checkout your original branch: git checkout feature/doing-stuff
  14. Cherry pick the eol fix commit and push: git cherry-pick [hash]
  15. Delete the eol branch and push
  16. Delete the eol repository clone (or keep around if you need to fix more branches)

Answer (score 1):

I've had CRLF line endings in working tree and LF in repository, because project folder was just copied from a Windows machine to a Linux one with **Git 1.8.3**. This is how I've reset line endings to LF:

- [`git status`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5237605#comment86240580_5238537) returns a list of all changed files
- `git diff` ignores line endings and returns files which are "really" changed
- [`comm -3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696111/1119602) compares lists and returns files from `git status` list which are not in `git diff` list
- [`git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147320/1119602) resets these files to HEAD

```
comm -3 <(git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | cut -c4- | sort) <(git diff --name-only | sort) | xargs git checkout HEAD --
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`merge.renormalize`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergerenormalize) configuration setting may be useful.