# Extra carriage return at end of every file causing problems in merge

Tags: git, git-merge, line-endings

In our git repo our files sometimes end up with additional carriage returns at the end of the line. When I view the files in vim I see;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>^M
<Root>^M
    <Child/>^M
</Root>^M
```

These extra `^M` will be on every line in the file. This causes problems when we merge because the other side of the merge will not have the additional `^M` and we get many merge conflicts. Passing options to ignore white space to `git merge` doesn't seem to help, it still conflicts on the whole file.

We use `git config core.autoclrf true`.

I need two things;

1. How do a search for all of these `^M` in my repo? Such that I can use some `git ls-files | grep <filter here> | sed 's/^M//'` to get rid of them.
2. How do I identify how they're being introduced?

Comment: As for **1**; `git ls-files | xargs dos2unix` ought to do it.

Comment: @Biffen thanks, do I need to consider any binary files with that?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641259/how-to-normalize-working-tree-line-endings-in-git).

Comment: `dos2unix` will just skip binary files (at least my version of it will, you might want to check yours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to [How to normalize working tree line endings in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15641259/1256452) are great for fixing up *new* commits.  (See both the accepted one, and the modern Git 2.16-or-later `git add --renormalize` trick.)

To deal more easily with *old* commits, use the renormalize extended-option: `git merge -X renormalize [other options you want if any] branch`.  This applies your current `.gitattributes` setting to all three versions of each file that is to be merged.

Comment: I don't know why, it might be because I don't _have_ a `.gitattributes` file, but `-X renormalize` didn't help compared to just running `git add --renormalize .` on each branch before merging.

Comment: You do in fact need a `.gitattributes` file to make the renormalize switch do something. It's really doing both CRLF *and* any clean/smudge filter operations, which are actually kind of the same thing inside Git: CRLF hacking is just a built-in clean/smudge filter.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using `unix2dos` (I'm on windows) as @Biffen suggested and also the answer in the linked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50645024/1281548).