# Jenkins 2.8 and git plugin 3.8 file format change to dos while git pull in workspace

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I am using Jenkins 2.8 on windows and git plugin 3.8 when git plugin clone/pull branch, the file format is changing to DOS and because of that on linux its failing shell script while execution.

Comment: You probably want to look at using [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and [normalizing your line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641259/how-to-normalize-working-tree-line-endings-in-git/).

Comment: Thanks @JohnSzakmeister  pointing to right direction.