# git svn keeps telling files need update

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have checked out an SVN repository using `git svn` with git 2.35.1. It has worked for a long time, but as of recently I get ghost-diffs:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   tools/a.cpp
    modified:   tools/b.cpp
    modified:   tools/c.cpp
    ...
```

If I `git checkout .` I get:

```
$ git checkout .
Updated 28 paths from the index
```

But nothing changes, i.e. `git status` keeps showing the same differences. I cannot `git svn rebase` from the remote `SVN` server:

```
$ git svn rebase
tools/a.cpp: needs update
tools/b.cpp: needs update
tools/c.cpp: needs update
...
```

When I use `git diff` I get full differences for all the files in this list. Using `git diff -w` says

```
$ git diff -w
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tools/a.cpp.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

I understand this is caused by whitespace changes between the local `git` checkout and the `SVN` server. I just cannot figure out any combination of options or configuration settings that will fix the problem.

*EDIT:*

I actually found a solution to update the repository: I checked out the revision before `tools/a.cpp` and friends were committed, and from there do a `git svn rebase`. This updates to the latest revision. But the problem is there again, and if I want to update further I have to repeat this revert and rebase process, so this is not a real solution, especially for large histories.

Comment: You've told Git to mess with your files. Tell Git *not* to mess with your files (turn off `core.autocrlf` and/or supply a `.gitattrbutes` file that tells Git files are not to have EOL modifications applied) and Git won't mess with them. Whether and how SVN will mess with them is a separate issue (to which i don't know the answer).

Comment: I actually didn't set any of these options and they are not set as far as I can see :(

Comment: Perhaps git-svn (the SVN add-on for Git) set them? I don't know, I've never used git-svn myself.

Answer (score 0):

With [Git 2.37, the warning will change and become](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332319/6309).

On a platform whose native line endings are not LF (e.g. Windows), those indexed files trigger:

> In the working copy of '`tools/a.cpp`', `LF` will be replaced by CRLF
> the next time Git touches it.

Make sure first and foremost that [git config `core.autocrlf` is set to `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309), and try again, to see if anything automagically change.
At least:

```
git config  --global core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: This did not change a thing, unfortunately :( I can even `git checkout tools/a.cpp` and it says `Updated 1 path from the index` and it still shows a modification for this file.

Comment: @hochl What would a [`git add --renormalize .`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56822362/6309) show you? Would there still be diffs in the status?

Comment: If I use that on `a.cpp` I get `Changes to be committed: ... modified:   tools/a.cpp`. `git diff --cached` shows a full diff, `git diff -w --cached` shows nothing.

Comment: @hochl That seems better. But it might interfer with git-svn.

Comment: I mean it actually made no difference and still does not work :(