# How to renormalize line endings in my working directory

Tags: git

I have files in a git repo with LF endings. Somehow some of the files in my working tree got converted to CRLF. Is there a way to convert the line endings in my working tree back to LF?

Note that I have a few files in the directory `.gitignore`d so I don't want to simply delete everything and check it out again (though if there's a way to only delete tracked files and check them out again that would work I guess).

Comment: Is `git add --renormalize` what you're looking for? And now I see your other question, so I guess it is not. I'll leave the comment around to reduce chance of it being repeated.

Comment: `git config core.eol lf` ?

Comment: And then what? Changing that setting doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: Maybe this link can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42135910/5950070

Comment: No, `git reset --hard` does not do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem with using `git checkout HEAD -- .` or `git checkout HEAD -- path` is that Git tries to optimize away the checkout, if Git thinks there's no need to *do* the checkout.<sup>1</sup>  As you noted in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64159429/1256452), `git reset` has the same optimization.

There are several ways to defeat the optimization.  The one you chose—using `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm -f`—works fine.  Another is to `touch` each file that you want Git to overwrite: this invalidates the cache data in Git's index.  Since `touch` doesn't actually *modify* the file, this can be simpler: `touch *` is usually fairly painless.  It doesn't handle subdirectories, though.  You could run `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 touch`, which is almost the same as in your answer.

---

<sup>1</sup>Obviously, if CRLF-handling for index-to-work-tree copying has changed since the previous index-to-work-tree copy step, this optimization is incorrect: Git *does* need to do the checkout.  But Git's cache doesn't realize that.  Possibly there should be a plumbing command, `git whack-cache` or `git frotz-index` or something, that just invalidates each cache entry, so as to force a real checkout.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a better solution than deleting all tracked files and checking them out again. In particular no variant of `git checkout -f -- .` or `git reset --hard` has any effect on the file.

As recommended [here](https://superuser.com/a/450115/80582):

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm -f
git checkout .
```

Not an elegant solution but it did work.

Comment: I wonder if you've seen [git checkout and reset a mess](https://redfin.engineering/two-commits-that-wrecked-the-user-experience-of-git-f0075b77eab1).
Adding the narrower focussed [switch and restore](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/08/git-2-23-switch-restore/) as correction. IOW try to rewrite checkout as restore. You'll need 2.23 or later

Comment: Neither reset nor checkout work - they are too "smart" and avoid modifying files if necessary. Arguably a bug in this case but I imagine fixing it would be difficult.