# core.eol = crlf sets crlfs on add and not on checkout

Tags: git

According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreeol) on `core-eol`

> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that are marked as text (either by having the text attribute set, or by having text=auto and Git auto-detecting the contents as text).

So question #1 is: Does core-eol work at all without having a .gitattributes file?

Question #2 is is this for checkout **to** the working directory or check-in **from** the working directory to index? Or both?

With git for windows 2.33.1 and global settings (no local) for `core.autocrlf = false` (so it does not override core.eol) and `core.eol = crlf` and running Git Bash (echo command > results in eol=LF)

```
1. git config --global core.autocrlf false
2. git config --global core.eol crlf
3. mkdir testEOL
4. cd testEOL
5. echo Hello > hello.txt // file has LF eol
6. git init
7. git add . // file still has LF eol in working directory
8. git commit -m "Initial commit"
9. echo "* text" > .gitattributes
10. git add . // file has LF eol, however -> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitattributes.
11. git commit -m "Git attributes"
12. echo New Line >> hello.txt
13. git add . // warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in hello.txt.
14. git commit -m "Change to hello"
14a. git rm hello.txt
15. git reset --hard HEAD // EDIT: hello.txt has CRLF
```

The answers to the questions seem:

1. No (line 7)
2. Check-in and check-out (lines 10,13 and 15) - after removal of files fist (see updated 14a)

Is it just my experiment or is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that `core.eol` only affects files with the `text` attribute set.  If that attribute is not set, the Git looks at `core.autocrlf` to determine it, and setting that would override the `core.eol` value.  So if you want to control the end of line, you'll need to use a `.gitattributes` file to set the attribute.

The `core.eol` option and and `eol` attribute affect only what is in the working tree.  Any file with the `text` attribute will have its line endings converted to LF when stored in the repository itself, and then that attribute or setting will determine what line endings it has in the working tree.

The warning you see is telling you that your file in the working tree has LF (because you created it with Unix shell tools) but your settings for the working tree have requested that it have CRLF in the working tree.  As a result, you might end up with a different behavior on a future checkout than you have now.

Doing a `git add` doesn't change the file in the working tree to have the specified endings, only add it to the repository with LF endings.  If you want to change the line endings in the working tree, you need to force the file to be checked out again, which you've done with `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to add to your last point, I think I stumbled upon another issue which is taht git reset --hard does not really work. I had to manually remove the file and then go reset --hard HEAD. I think this had to to with some mysterious cache -> from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64159070/how-to-renormalize-line-endings-in-my-working-directory

Answer (score 0):

> core.eol = crlf sets crlfs on add and not on checkout

this is wrong. Working around the eol-handling limitations of toolchains you don't have is always going to be a bit of a minefield, and you've stepped on a few of them here.

```
git init testeol; cd $_                                                                                                                                                                                               
git config core.autocrlf false                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
git config core.eol crlf                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
echo Hello >hello.txt;          git add .; git commit -m Initial                                                                                                                                                                               
echo '* text' >.gitattributes;  git add .; git commit -m .gitattributes                                                                                                                                                                        
echo New line >>hello.txt;                 git commit -am 'new hello line'
```

So, here's a few of the mines you hit: you've told Git `core.eol crlf`, that you want it to work with tools that expect crlf eol's for "text", but for instance you leave `hello.txt` unspecified, which means you don't want eol translation done for that, but then you add an attribute that says you do want it done for that and everything else . . . but the files you add don't have crlf eol's, which means you're working with tools that don't generate and may not be expecting crlf eol's despite what your config says. So combine that with you not forcing Git to retrieve the file from the repository, *and* Git itself not natively using or expecting crlf eols, and, yeah. Minefield.

`core.eof` does crlf translation on checkout.

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in hello.txt.                                                                     
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory                                                 
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitattributes.                                                                
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

on add are warning you that you added a file that has LF line endings in your work tree but your current setup is set up to replace those on checkout *to* your work tree with CRLF, because they're explicitly marked as `text` in `.gitattributes` and your config says you want crlf eol's in those.

But `git add` is not `git checkout` and you haven't done a checkout of those files yet, so they'll still have their original line endings in your work tree until you do that.

I think the messages could maybe be more helpful for newbies, I'm not sure exactly how. Best first guess I can come up with?  Maybe that first message could read

```
warning: when Git writes new content to hello.txt it will replace LF with CRLF
```

and the second line could read

```
The file you added is still in the working directory, with LF line endings, unaltered.
```

Comment: I had two questions - I wanted to test if core.eol without gitattributes would do anything. Apparently, not. Also, I agree that the warning that I get on git add should be more specific that this conversion will take place on check-out and that the file will still be checked-in as LF (normalized).

Comment: The config docs for core.eol say "Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that are marked as text (either by having the text attribute set, or by having text=auto and Git auto-detecting the contents as text)", are the attributes docs not clear about how to set attributes? Also, I don't think there's any value in overlooking false premises when they're relevant, so I tend to address those.

Comment: My confusion stems from this article: https://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/. My maybe false premise was that core.eol predates the text attribute in .gitattributes (which should have been added in git 1.7.2). As it stands in the current documentation, it looks that core.eol cannot work without text in .gitattributes but that would seem like a breaking change.

Comment: Took me two minutes to say `git log --grep core.eol`, find the commit that introduced the config item, say `git show 942e7747678ecf5f118ea5b2d0c763166de21f3a` to get the diffs and see that the docs for core.eol (which you and I both quoted) have not changed since it was introduced in 2010.  Why you think what you think is not clear; I don't see where you got it from, not from the official docs or even that blog post, which seems like a valuable historical-context description for people who just need a bit of orientation.

Comment: yeah, I decided to get through the git repo / documentation / release notes to do the same eventually. It wasn't clear in the blogpost because in it core.eol was introduced in the Background section, followed by Old System which is core.autocrlf, and New Section which is about .gitattribtutes' text attribute.