# Grep list of files returned from git status

Tags: bash, git

So I am trying to clean up a script I have that gets the list of currently staged files using `git status` to return the relative file path of each staged file. I have looked at the documentation for `git status` to see if there was a way to get it to return the *absolute* path of each staged file, but there doesn't seem to be an option for that and `git ls files` nor `git diff` will work for this since the specific use case is during a merge.

During the merge, using `git diff` returns nothing, while `git status` does show all of the staged files, so I am stuck using `git status`.

From this list I have, I want to then `grep` through the list of files to extract any line(s) that contain the string `"Path: "` and output it. Basically, I have a list of staged .yml files and I want to extract all changes to the `Path` property in those ymls. Heres what I have so far:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for file in `git status -s -uno | sed s/^..//`
    do
        relativePath=$(echo $file | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | tr -d '"')
        startPath=`pwd`
        grep "Path: " "$startPath/$relativePath"
    done
unset IFS
```

Explanation:

`git status -s -uno | sed s/^..//`

- I am piping the result of `git status` into `sed` to remove any extra whitespace

`relativePath=$(echo $file | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | tr -d '"')`

- I echo the file path and pipe it into `sed` to remove any extra spaces that weren't removed from the initial `sed` call in the start of the `for` loop. I then pipe that into `tr` to remove the first and last double quotes from the string since I need to combine that relative path with my starting path in order to get the complete path.

`` startPath=`pwd` ``

`grep "Path: " "$startPath/$relativePath"`

- Store the current working directory in a variable, then combine it with our relative path and pass that into `grep`

This script works and extracts the data that I need, but I feel like there is a much cleaner way I could be doing this. Is there a way I can get `git status` to return the full path of each staged file so I don't have to have my second `$startPath` variable that I combine with my `$relativePath` thats passed into `grep`?

Comment: Here is a question about getting the full paths from git status.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237605/how-can-i-run-git-status-and-just-get-the-filenames

Comment: `git diff-index --cached --name-only @`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (correct) way to do this is by using [git grep](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) combined with [git ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files). The latter is used as a selector for grep.

**Recursive search of modified tracked files using a pattern:**

```
git grep -r 'pattern' -- `git ls-files -m`
```

**Recursive search of all tracked files using a pattern:**

```
git grep -r "pattern" .
```

Note that this grep search doesn't cover untracked files. You must add them first so that git can see them.

Comment: Even though this answer doesn't answer the question directly I think that it's the better answer because it solves the problem in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably call `git status` from inside the repo, all paths will be relative to $PWD, so you can just add it in place, yes?

```
$: git status -s | sed "s@^[^ ]* @$PWD/@"
```