# Force git status to show only filenames, without path

Tags: git

Is there a possibility to use e.g **sed** tool to make **git** status display only the filename, without any path? Instead of:

```
/relative/path/to/file/filename.py
```

I would welcome just:

```
filename.py
```

I have very long paths in my project, what makes the output of git status hardly readable.

Example of git status output:

```
modified:   d/da/mvp/view/dialogelement/composite/Tab.py
modified:   da/dab/core/api/Messages.py
```

Comment: If all the changes are in one directory, you can get some mileage by cd'ing into that folder.

Comment: Nope, it's in multiples dirs

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now. Could you post a sample output (fake dir or two) of git status?

Comment: I added example to main question

Comment: I think is same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237605/how-can-i-run-git-status-and-just-get-the-filenames

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run "git status" and just get the filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237605/how-can-i-run-git-status-and-just-get-the-filenames)

Comment: Just to clarify, your output lines actually look like this, right? `# modified:   da/dab/core/api/Messages.py`.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bash:

```
for fname in $(git status --short | cut -d ' ' -f 2); do basename $fname; done
```

Will gives you expected output. But be careful, directories will appears as files.

Comment: It has some disadvantage - when there are sections of Modified and Untracked files, it shows only the lower one, but it's a great help anyway. Thanks

Comment: @Krzysztof tell me more please, looks like fun to dig in

Comment: Your command doesn't detect anything above:

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

Comment: @Krzysztof really? here is my output https://gist.github.com/arount/840115d3deca8048ef57ca693aff919d (`four` is outputed by my command)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
git status | sed 's-\(#\t\+modified: \+\)\(.*/\)\([^/]\+\)-\1.../\3-'
```

This will replace any text starting with `modified:` and a bunch of spaces containing slashes with `.../` until the last slash. The prefix, spaces and last part of the path will be untouched.

A similar result can be achieved with fewer backslashes using the `-E` or `-r` flag:

```
git status | sed -E 's-(#\t+modified: +)(.*/)([^/]+)-\1.../\3-'
```

Comment: Nope, it only removed the word 'modified:  ' in the beginning

Comment: @Krzysztof. Updated

Comment: @Krzysztof. I've updated my answer (after testing this time) :)