# Print welcome message in git bash in Windows 7

Tags: git, git-bash

How do I print a welcome message containing my `git` aliases when I open a `git bash` in Windows?

Comment: which command would you run manually to get the output you want to see?

Comment: I don't know, I may have to do this manually, like `echo "Available aliases: au : add -u, ct = commit...`

Comment: which _git_ command would you run manually?

Comment: Some command that prints a welcome message when I open git bash from Windows

Comment: You would still need my answer to input an (updated) list of aliases in /etc/motd though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of [`/etc/motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/motd.5.html) are displayed on the terminal after an interactive login to the Bash shell (`bash --login`). If the version of *Git for Windows* you have omitted the file [`/etc/motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/motd.5.html), create one with `cat` or your favorite editor.

```
# == Git Bash on Windows ==
#  - /etc/motd  = Message of the Day 
# - - - - - - - - - - - - -    
cat > /etc/motd
Welcome to the Git Bash Shell
- Try "pwd -W" versus "pwd -L"
- - - - - - - - -
```

*CTRL-D*

Answer (score 4):

Simply define a `HOME` environment variable, (not defined in the `git-bash.bat` script included in msysgit).

In the directory you have chosen (for instance: `%USERPROFILE%`), define a .bashrc file, with the following content:

```
git config --get-regexp alias
```

(from "[How to list/show Git aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066325/how-to-list-show-git-aliases)")

That will display all your git aliases each time you open a bash session with msysgit.

```
alias.st status
alias.lg log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)%an%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relati    ve
alias.co checkout
alias.ci commit
alias.br branch
alias.lo !sh -c 'git log $1' -
alias.impact !git ls-files -z | xargs -0n1 git blame -w -C | sed -r 's/^[^(]+\((.*) [0-9]{4}-.*/\1/' | sed -r 's/ +$//' | sort -f | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

However, the [OP Wilhelmsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340942/wilhelmsen) asks [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120936/print-welcome-message-in-git-bash-in-windows-7/13121768#comment17842770_13121768):

> Do you know how I can omit the word alias on the print?

Sure, this is a basic [bash String manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) operation:

```
a=$(git config --get-regexp alias)
echo "${a//alias./}"
```

That will display:

```
st status
lg log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)%an%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
co checkout
ci commit
br branch
lo !sh -c 'git log $1' -
impact !git ls-files -z | xargs -0n1 git blame -w -C | sed -r 's/^[^(]+\((.*) [0-9]{4}-.*/\1/' | sed -r 's/ +$//' | sort -f | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Note the `${a//alias./}` in order to replace *all* '`alias.`' from the String '`a`' by an empty String.
And the double quotes for the `echo "$..."` are mandatory to keep the newlines in place. (otherwise, all the aliases would be displayed on *one* line).

Comment: @Wilhelmsen http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519 or http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html (ok, I didn't see your last edit to your comment)

Comment: Do you know how I can omit the word `alias` on the print?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen I have edited the answer to address your last comment/question, removing the '`alias.`' from the output.