# Verifying signed git commits?

Tags: git

With newer versions of `git` it's possible to sign individual commits (in addition to tags) with a PGP key:

```bash
git commit -m "some message" -S
```

And you can show these signatures in the output of `git log` with the `--show-signature` option:

```
$ git log --show-signature
commit 93bd0a7529ef347f8dbca7efde43f7e99ab89515
gpg: Signature made Fri 28 Jun 2013 02:28:41 PM EDT using RSA key ID AC1964A8
gpg: Good signature from "Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>"
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Fri Jun 28 14:28:41 2013 -0400

    this is a test
```

But is there a way to programatically verify the signature on a given commit other than by grepping the output of `git log`? I'm looking for the commit equivalent of `git tag -v` -- something that will provide an exit code indicating whether or not there was a valid signature on a given commit.

Comment: I think that should be `git commit ...` and `git log ...`. As far as I know, `gpg` has not added subcommands that get passed to `git` transparently... I don't have any repos to test with, but does `git show --show-signature <commitish>` work?

Comment: `show_signature` only adds things to the output (see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/log-tree.c#L370).

Comment: Note: you will soon have `--raw` for `git verify-tag`/`git verify-commit`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32038784/6309)

Comment: Note: With GIt 2.11 (Q4 2016), `git log` introduces additional status codes `E`, `X`, `Y`, `R` for `ERRSIG`, `EXPSIG`, `EXPKEYSIG`, and `REVKEYSIG`, so that a user of `%G?` gets more information. See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32038784/6309)

Comment: With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), the new config `gpg.minTrustLevel` can help when using `git verify-tag`/`verify -commit`. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32038784/6309).

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Just in case someone comes to this page through a search engine, like I did: New tools have been made available in the two years since the question was posted:  There are now git commands for this task: `git verify-commit` and `git verify-tag` can be used to verify commits and tags, respectively.

Comment: I will just add that if these commands return empty, it means that there is no signature for the element (tag or commit)

Answer (score 71):

Note: up to git 2.5, [`git verify-commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-commit) and [`git verify-tag`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-tag) only displayed a human readable message.
If you want to automate the check, git 2.6+ (Q3 2015) adds another output.

See [commit e18443e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e18443ece711564145d545b650851c4615717128), [commit aeff29d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeff29dd4dab01b497b2a2cf73e982e846a5fe4c), [commit ca194d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca194d50b84b53a0b711fef46d1a47657ec5da41), [commit 434060e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/434060ec6d9bf50f095db901da3fb9b557e11df1), [commit 8e98e5f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e98e5f27aba812c0f095b7e546871e14a4139f6), [commit a4cc18f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4cc18f2934b8d2f00c7c3e11107acb6bfafe2c6), [commit d66aeff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d66aeff21e8ce92d742aa04c5e59ca3eee5e39d8) (21 Jun 2015) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ba12cb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba12cb299f831f29c256c644b01108710c2629e6), 03 Aug 2015)</sup>

> ## `verify-tag`/`verify-commit`: add option to print raw gpg status information

> `verify-tag`/`verify-commit` by default displays human-readable output on standard error.
> **However, it can also be useful to get access to the raw gpg status information, which is machine-readable, allowing automated implementation of signing policy**.
>
> Add a **`--raw` option** to make `verify-tag` produce the gpg status information on standard error instead of the human-readable format.

Plus:

> `verify-tag` exits successfully if the signature is good but the key is
> untrusted. `verify-commit` exits unsuccessfully.
> This divergence in behavior is unexpected and unwanted.
> Since `verify-tag` existed earlier, add a failing test to have `verify-commit` share `verify-tag`'s behavior.

---

git 2.9 (June 2016) update the [git merge doc](https://github.com/git/git/blob/be6ec17822e523ef4700c612f1ec2baedacd1227/Documentation/merge-options.txt#L90-L96):

See [commit 05a5869](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05a5869a01779e6fb55535aff9b01716aac42dcf) (13 May 2016) by [Keller Fuchs (``)](https://github.com/).
Helped-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit be6ec17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be6ec17822e523ef4700c612f1ec2baedacd1227), 17 May 2016)</sup>

```
--verify-signatures:
--no-verify-signatures:
```

> Verify that the tip commit of the side branch being merged is signed with a valid key, i.e. **a key that has a valid uid: in the default trust model, this means the signing key has been signed by a trusted key.
>
> If the tip commit of the side branch is not signed with a valid key, the merge is aborted**.

---

Update Git 2.10 (Q3 2016)

See [commit b624a3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b624a3e67f498cb41f704c9bd28e7d53076611c8) (16 Aug 2016) by [Linus Torvalds (`torvalds`)](https://github.com/torvalds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 83d9eb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83d9eb0ad85eeb88cb1dce88cf86458c6d3e57f1), 19 Aug 2016)</sup>

> ### `gpg-interface`: prefer "long" key format output when verifying pgp signatures

> "`git log --show-signature`" and other commands that display the verification status of PGP signature now shows the longer key-id, as 32-bit key-id is so last century.
>
> Linus's original was rebased to apply to the maintenance track just in case binary distributors that are stuck in the past want to take it to their older codebase.

---

Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016) will even be more precise.

See [commit 661a180](https://github.com/git/git/commit/661a1806819ca98c446f82b19e6c98fa174d33a4) (12 Oct 2016) by [Michael J Gruber (`mjg`)](https://github.com/mjg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 56d268b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56d268bafff7538f82c01d3c9c07bdc54b2993b1), 26 Oct 2016)</sup>

> The GPG verification status shown in "`%G?`" pretty format specifier was not rich enough to differentiate a signature made by an expired key, a signature made by a revoked key, etc.
> **New output letters have been assigned to express them**.
>
> According to [gpg2's `doc/DETAILS`](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/DETAILS;h=a264e53eecf990cd2469a47bd95a2ff7bbfac1de;hb=refs/heads/master#l368):
>
> > For each signature only one of the codes `GOODSIG`, `BADSIG`, `EXPSIG`, `EXPKEYSIG`, `REVKEYSIG` or `ERRSIG` will be emitted.

The [`git pretty-format` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/56d268bafff7538f82c01d3c9c07bdc54b2993b1/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L146-L153) now include:

> - '`%G?`': show
> - "`G`" for a good (valid) signature,
> - "`B`" for a bad signature,
> - "`U`" for a good signature with unknown validity,
> - "`X`" for a good signature that has expired,
> - "`Y`" for a good signature made by an expired key,
> - "`R`" for a good signature made by a revoked key,
> - "`E`" if the signature cannot be checked (e.g. missing key)
>   and "`N`" for no signature

---

Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) "`git tag`" and "`git verify-tag`" **learned to put GPG verification status in their "`--format=<placeholders>`" output format**.

See [commit 4fea72f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fea72f4f76addb6b49ca4f5b97f66a6bda46985), [commit 02c5433](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02c5433e1620e49daa48c7ca0b30b80a39ec08ad), [commit ff3c8c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff3c8c8f124b26559232857fd37b67a0dd99600d) (17 Jan 2017) by [Santiago Torres (`SantiagoTorres`)](https://github.com/SantiagoTorres).
See [commit 07d347c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07d347cf9ac13c3d1746ae368f6e72afbe82dc15), [commit 2111aa7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2111aa794bb420f767895682232b494d3461ab31), [commit 94240b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94240b918f70560393516aa8f98edb877d582c69) (17 Jan 2017) by [Lukas Puehringer (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 237bdd9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/237bdd9ddbe52eb651787af1929d8832ce37c322), 31 Jan 2017)</sup>

> Adding `--format` to `git tag -v` mutes the default output of the GPG
> verification and instead prints the formatted tag object.
> This allows callers to cross-check the tagname from refs/tags with
> the tagname from the tag object header upon GPG verification.

---

Git 2.16 (Q1 2018) will allow the commit signature verification to be even more automated, with the `merge.verifySignatures` configuration variable.

See [commit 7f8ca20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f8ca20a44094dda6e6c74013a36c078cbffc548), [commit ca779e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca779e82c9f263dfdea2a73a4f5494b37bc8aae7) (10 Dec 2017) by [Hans Jerry Illikainen (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0433d53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0433d533f13671f4313c31e34707f0f5281a18e0), 28 Dec 2017)</sup>

> ### `merge`: add config option for `verifySignatures`

> `git merge --verify-signatures` can be used to verify that the tip commit
> of the branch being merged in is properly signed, but it's cumbersome to
> have to specify that every time.
>
> Add a configuration option that enables this behaviour by default, which
> can be overridden by `--no-verify-signatures`.

The [`git merge` config man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ca779e82c9f263dfdea2a73a4f5494b37bc8aae7/Documentation/merge-config.txt#L29-L31) now reads:

> ```
> merge.verifySignatures:
> ```

> If true, this is equivalent to the `--verify-signatures` command line option.

---

Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) is even more helpful, since "`git verify-tag`" and "`git verify-commit`" have been taught to use the exit status of underlying "`gpg --verify`" to signal bad or untrusted signature they found.

Note: with Git 2.19, [`gpg.format` that can be set to "`openpgp`" or "`x509`", and `gpg.<format>.program` that is used to specify what program to use to deal with the format) to allow x.509 certs with CMS via "`gpgsm`" to be used instead of `openpgp` via "`gnupg`".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919818/6309)

See [commit 4e5dc9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e5dc9ca179931b4dc39b32f06facc5a31091403) (09 Aug 2018) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
Helped-by: [Vojtech Myslivec (`VojtechMyslivec`)](https://github.com/VojtechMyslivec), [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204), and [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4d34122](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d34122eef19c39415d38b4963572770f96a9317), 20 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `gpg-interface`: propagate exit status from `gpg` back to the callers

> When gpg-interface API unified support for signature verification codepaths for signed tags and signed commits in mid 2015 at around v2.6.0-rc0~114, we accidentally loosened the GPG signature verification.
>
> Before that change, signed commits were verified by looking for "`G`"ood signature from GPG, while ignoring the exit status of "`gpg --verify`" process, while signed tags were verified by simply passing the exit status of `"gpg --verify`" through.
>
> The unified code we currently have ignores the exit status of "`gpg --verify`" and returns successful verification when the signature matches an unexpired key regardless of the trust placed on the key (i.e. in addition to "`G`"ood ones, we accept "`U`"ntrusted ones).
>
> Make these commands signal failure with their exit status when underlying "`gpg --verify`" (or the custom command specified by "`gpg.program`" configuration variable) does so.
> This essentially changes their behaviour in a backward incompatible way to reject signatures that have been made with untrusted keys even if they correctly verify, as that is how "`gpg --verify`" behaves.
>
> Note that the code still overrides a zero exit status obtained from "`gpg`" (or `gpg.program`) if the output does not say the signature is good or computes correctly but made with untrusted keys, to catch a poorly written wrapper around "`gpg`" the user may give us.
>
> We could exclude "`U`"ntrusted support from this fallback code, but that would be making two backward incompatible changes in a single commit, so let's avoid that for now.
> A follow-up change could do so if desired.

---

> the key is needed to be trusted/signed before do any encryption

On the trust side, there is progress:
With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), `gpg.minTrustLevel` configuration variable has been introduced to tell various signature verification codepaths the required minimum trust level.

See [commit 54887b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54887b46890582e60fcb8ee1f287f62870c2ac0f) (27 Dec 2019) by [Hans Jerry Illikainen (`illikainen`)](https://github.com/illikainen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 11ad30b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11ad30b887e2512df1c7703913048827080601e1), 30 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`gpg-interface`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54887b46890582e60fcb8ee1f287f62870c2ac0f): add minTrustLevel as a configuration option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Hans Jerry Illikainen</sup>

> Previously, signature verification for merge and pull operations checked if the key had a trust-level of either `TRUST_NEVER` or `TRUST_UNDEFINED` in `verify_merge_signature()`.
>
> If that was the case, the process `die()`'d.
>
> The other code paths that did signature verification relied entirely on the return code from `check_commit_signature()`.
>
> And signatures made with a good key, irregardless of its trust level, was considered valid by `check_commit_signature()`.
>
> This difference in behavior might **induce users to erroneously assume that the trust level of a key in their keyring is always considered by Git, even for operations where it is not (e.g. during a `verify-commit` or `verify-tag`)**.
>
> The way it worked was by [`gpg-interface.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/54887b46890582e60fcb8ee1f287f62870c2ac0f/gpg-interface.c) storing the result from the key/signature status *and* the lowest-two trust levels in the `result` member of the `signature_check` structure (the last of these status lines that were encountered got written to `result`).
>
> These are documented in GPG under the subsection `General status codes` and `Key related`, respectively.
>
> The GPG documentation says the following on the [`TRUST_ status` codes](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/doc/DETAILS;h=%5Bbd00006e933ac56719b1edd2478ecd79273eae72%5D(https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd00006e933ac56719b1edd2478ecd79273eae72);hb=refs/heads/master):
>
> > ---
>
> > These are several similar status codes:
>
> > ```
> > - TRUST_UNDEFINED <error_token>
> > - TRUST_NEVER     <error_token>
> > - TRUST_MARGINAL  [0  [<validation_model>]]
> > - TRUST_FULLY     [0  [<validation_model>]]
> > - TRUST_ULTIMATE  [0  [<validation_model>]]
> > ```
> >
> > For good signatures one of these status lines are emitted to indicate the validity of the key used to create the signature.
> > The error token values are currently only emitted by gpgsm.
> >
> > ---
>
> My interpretation is that the trust level is conceptually different from the validity of the key and/or signature.
>
> That seems to also have been the assumption of the old code in `check_signature()` where a result of '`G`' (as in `GOODSIG`) and '`U`' (as in `TRUST_NEVER` or `TRUST_UNDEFINED)` were both considered a success.
>
> The two cases where a result of '`U`' had special meaning were in `verify_merge_signature()` (where this caused `git` to `die()`) and in `format_commit_one()` (where it affected the output of the `%G?` format specifier).
>
> I think it makes sense to refactor the processing of `TRUST_ status` lines such that users can configure a minimum trust level that is enforced globally, rather than have individual parts of `git` (e.g. merge) do it themselves (except for a grace period with backward compatibility).
>
> I also think it makes sense to not store the trust level in the same struct member as the key/signature status.
>
> While the presence of a `TRUST_ status` code does imply that the signature is good (see the first paragraph in the included snippet above), as far as I can tell, the order of the status lines from GPG isn't well-defined; thus it would seem plausible that the trust level could be overwritten with the key/signature status if they were stored in the same member of the `signature_check` structure.
>
> This patch introduces a new configuration option: **`gpg.minTrustLevel`**.
>
> It consolidates trust-level verification to [`gpg-interface.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/54887b46890582e60fcb8ee1f287f62870c2ac0f/gpg-interface.c) and adds a new `trust_level` member to the `signature_check` structure.
>
> Backward-compatibility is maintained by introducing a special case in `verify_merge_signature()` such that if no user-configurable `gpg.minTrustLevel` is set, then the old behavior of rejecting `TRUST_UNDEFINED` and `TRUST_NEVER` is enforced.
>
> If, on the other hand, `gpg.minTrustLevel` is set, then that value overrides the old behavior.
>
> Similarly, the `%G?` format specifier will continue show '`U`' for signatures made with a key that has a trust level of `TRUST_UNDEFINED` or `TRUST_NEVER,` even though the '`U`' character no longer exist in the `result` member of the `signature_check` structure.
>
> A new format specifier, `%GT`, is also introduced for users that want to show all possible trust levels for a signature.
>
> Another approach would have been to simply drop the trust-level requirement in `verify_merge_signature()`.
>
> This would also have made the behavior consistent with other parts of git that perform signature verification.
>
> However, requiring a minimum trust level for signing keys does seem to have a real-world use-case.
>
> For example, the build system used by the Qubes OS project currently parses the raw output from verify-tag in order to assert a minimum trust level for keys used to [sign git tags](https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-builder/blob/9674c1991deef45b1a1b1c71fddfab14ba50dccf/scripts/verify-git-tag#L43).

The [`git config gpg` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/54887b46890582e60fcb8ee1f287f62870c2ac0f/Documentation/config/gpg.txt#L22-L29) now includes:

> ### gpg.minTrustLevel:

> Specifies a minimum trust level for signature verification.
> If this option is unset, then signature verification for merge operations require a key with at least `marginal` trust.
> Other operations that perform signature verification require a key with at least `undefined` trust.
> Setting this option overrides the required trust-level for all operations.  Supported values, in increasing order of significance:
>
> - `undefined`
> - `never`
> - `marginal`
> - `fully`
> - `ultimate`

---

With [Git 2.26 (Q1 2020)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3658d77f8e563e77658d9e44df5e24f08ca99e3a), "`git show`" and others gave an object name in raw format in its error output, which has been corrected to give it in hex.

> ### show_one_mergetag: print non-parent in hex form.

> When a mergetag names a non-parent, which can occur after a shallow
> clone, its hash was previously printed as raw data.
> Print it in hex form instead.

Tested with `git -C shallow log --graph --show-signature -n1 plain-shallow` after a `git clone --depth 1 --no-local . shallow`

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), the code to interface with GnuPG has been refactored.

See [commit 6794898](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67948981983b336eab2fa7e6a0e125d529391dfc), [commit f1e3df3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1e3df316992d32b17ee27385e4c644ef7b66cc1) (04 Mar 2020) by [Hans Jerry Illikainen (`illikainen`)](https://github.com/illikainen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fa82be9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa82be982dfc5b463a125991a2d381f1cd0ad9eb), 27 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`gpg-interface`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67948981983b336eab2fa7e6a0e125d529391dfc): prefer `check_signature()` for GPG verification
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Hans Jerry Illikainen</sup>

> This commit refactors the use of `verify_signed_buffer()` outside of [`gpg-interface.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67948981983b336eab2fa7e6a0e125d529391dfc/gpg-interface.c) to use `check_signature()` instead.
>
> It also turns `verify_signed_buffer()` into a file-local function since it's now only invoked internally by `check_signature()`.
>
> There were previously two globally scoped functions used in different parts of Git to perform GPG signature verification: `verify_signed_buffer()` and `check_signature()`.
>
> Now only `check_signature()` is used.
>
> The `verify_signed_buffer()` function doesn't guard against [duplicate signatures as described by Michał Górny](https://dev.gentoo.org/%7Emgorny/articles/attack-on-git-signature-verification.html).
>
> Instead it only ensures a non-erroneous exit code from GPG and the presence of at least one `GOODSIG` status field.
>
> This stands in contrast with `check_signature()` that returns an error if more than one signature is encountered.
>
> The lower degree of verification makes the use of `verify_signed_buffer()` problematic if callers don't parse and validate the various parts of the GPG status message themselves.
>
> And processing these messages seems like a task that should be reserved to [`gpg-interface.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67948981983b336eab2fa7e6a0e125d529391dfc/gpg-interface.c) with the function `check_signature()`.
>
> Furthermore, the use of `verify_signed_buffer()` makes it difficult to introduce new functionality that relies on the content of the GPG status lines.
>
> Now all operations that does signature verification share a single entry point to [`gpg-interface.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67948981983b336eab2fa7e6a0e125d529391dfc/gpg-interface.c).
>
> **This makes it easier to propagate changed or additional functionality in GPG signature verification to all parts of Git, without having odd edge-cases that don't perform the same degree of verification**.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), signed commits and tags now allow verification of objects, whose two object names (one in SHA-1, the other in SHA-256) are both signed.

See [commit 9b27b49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b27b49240f6bf760ff58d917491bec0981aaf9f), [commit 88bce0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88bce0e24c8f777fce1f726b4553bd32286bba04), [commit 937032e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/937032e14aaf1eab59c96dd78938be1c48c648e1), [commit 482c119](https://github.com/git/git/commit/482c119186987110bfccf705a5ac75d399b08766) (11 Feb 2021), and [commit 1fb5cf0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fb5cf0da657ef046c4eb4d0de6f2defb2fb09c6), [commit 83dff3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83dff3eb2ed9cd750ec89f3dc5bab44b16119743) (18 Jan 2021) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 15af6e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15af6e6fee54632358798bef548d89dd3764805d), 22 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fb5cf0da657ef046c4eb4d0de6f2defb2fb09c6): ignore additional signatures when parsing signed commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> When we create a commit with multiple signatures, neither of these signatures includes the other.
> Consequently, when we produce the payload which has been signed so we can verify the commit, we must strip off any other signatures, or the payload will differ from what was signed.
> Do so, and in preparation for verifying with multiple algorithms, pass the algorithm we want to verify into `parse_signed_commit`.

---

[Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356754/brandon) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371955/verifying-signed-git-commits/32038784#comment124980964_32038784) a `git log` alias, which shows key states:

```sh
[alias]
    lg = "!f() { \
        git log --all --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold yellow)<sig>%G?</sig>%C(reset) %C(red)%h%C(reset) -%C(yellow)%d%C(reset) %s %C(green)(%cr) %C(blue)<%an>%C(reset)' | \
        sed \
        -e 's#<sig>G</sig>#Good#' \
        -e 's#<sig>B</sig>#\\nBAD \\nBAD \\nBAD \\nBAD \\nBAD#' \
        -e 's#<sig>U</sig>#Unknown#' \
        -e 's#<sig>X</sig>#Expired#' \
        -e 's#<sig>Y</sig>#Expired Key#' \
        -e 's#<sig>R</sig>#Revoked#' \
        -e 's#<sig>E</sig>#Missing Key#' \
        -e 's#<sig>N</sig>#None#' | \
        less -r; \
    }; f"
```

Comment: Great job keeping this updated with the latest changes  It took me forever to get to the comments 

Comment: Is there a way to color `%G?` based on what it returns?

Comment: @Brandon Not that I know of.

Comment: I was able to take inspiration form here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772985/1356754 to pipe it through sed

Comment: @Brandon That would work indeed, well done. Have you made a git alias? And if so, what does it looks like?

Comment: I opted to go with string substitution without colors, but color codes could be added to those strings.  This is what I am using for my custom log alias. https://pastebin.com/raw/x9AYMkRT

Comment: @Brandon Nice! Can I edit the answer with your alias?

Comment: @VonC, yes, but keep in mind that with the current implementation you won't be able to pass additional arguments to log

Answer (score 6):

A cursory inspection of the code suggests that there is no such direct method.

All of the tests in the git source rely on `grep`ping the output of `git show` (see [t/t7510-signed-commit.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t7510-signed-commit.sh) for the tests).

You can customize the output using something like `--pretty "%H %G?%"` to make it easy to parse.

It appears you can ask `git merge` to verify a signature but again, its tests rely on `grep` (see [t/t7612-merge-verify-signatures.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t7612-merge-verify-signatures.sh)). It does look like an invalid signature will cause `git merge` to exit with a bad signature, so you could potentially today hack around this by doing a test merge somewhere and throwing out that merge but that seems worse than just calling grep.