# Creating a signed commit via API

Tags: git, github, digital-signature, commit

I am working on creating a signed commit via API in GitHub workflow so I just read document https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit

I am creating a payload file with a sample data tree

```
827efc6d56897b048c772eb4087f854f46256132 parent
7d1b31e74ee336d15cbd21741bc88a537ed063a0 author Mona Octocat
<octocat@github.com> 1215576810 +1200 committer Mona Octocat
<octocat@github.com> 1215576810 +1200

my commit message
```

But I am getting Invalid in the sign commit I want to know what actually is required to do a signed commit via API as I am unable to find any blog or post.

Comment: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-13-a-simpler-api-for-authoring-commits/ Fixed. No need for much work, automatically signed and code shortend with GraphQL mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should try to understand how a Git commit is signed.

To save some text, refer to [What data is being signed when you `git commit --gpg-sign=<key-id>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23584990/5958455) for details of the signed data - I'm going to only reproduce it here. Apparently you won't have GitHub's private key, so you must bring your own key. Upload it in [GitHub settings](https://github.com/settings/keys) so it becomes "trusted".

First, perform the to-be-signed commit locally so you have the commit data. For example, I'm using [the `HEAD` commit](https://github.com/iBug/iBug-source/commit/351e7fe08176e35a9e4c91be2122921ada3cac3a) of my repository, at the time of writing this answer:

```sh
~ $ cd iBug-source
~/iBug-source $ git log -1 HEAD
commit 351e7fe08176e35a9e4c91be2122921ada3cac3a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: iBug <git@ibugone.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 16 02:51:19 2020 +0800

    Force redirect
```

Extract the payload for the GPG signature (the message part) from Git. You'll need to strip off the trailing newline (as I do with `perl`).

```sh
~/iBug-source $ git cat-file commit HEAD
tree fe9d12667f47065738ebcb3f6dd665a4150be267
parent fb4c5fb11f79142fc1f6f86fd7442274839626fb
author iBug <git@ibugone.com> 1605466279 +0800
committer iBug <git@ibugone.com> 1605466626 +0800

Force redirect
~/iBug-source $ git cat-file commit HEAD | perl -pe 'chomp if eof' > commit
```

Now I have the message payload in the `commit` file. I want to create a signature using my own key.

Because Git expects a signature algorithm of SHA-1, I supplied `--digest-algo SHA1` to the CLI invocation. I also added `--clear-sign` (signature only, do not include message body) and `--armor` (output ASCII armor format)

```sh
~/iBug-source $ gpg --clear-sign --digest-algo SHA1 --armor --local-user 0xA2C63304 commit
```

The above command produced the file `commit.asc` with the following content:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=YxhM
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

This is the signature you want in the `signature` JSON field, as given by [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#create-a-commit--parameters).

Construct the API payload JSON:

```json
{
  "message": "Force redirect",
  "author": {
    "name": "iBug",
    "email": "git@ibugone.com",
    "date": "2020-11-16T02:51:19+08:00"
  },
  "committer": {
    "name": "iBug",
    "email": "git@ibugone.com",
    "date": "2020-11-16T02:57:06+08:00"
  },
  "parents": [
    "fb4c5fb11f79142fc1f6f86fd7442274839626fb"
  ],
  "tree": "fe9d12667f47065738ebcb3f6dd665a4150be267",
  "signature": "-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----\n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\nDg4ukCQkabA+lFB3AiVdhhLZT5ucjSFFfnLUkwaULRP5XEgQhH8=\n=YxhM\n-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----\n"
}
```

Send it to GitHub API:

```sh
~/iBug-source $ curl -X POST \
  -H 'Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data @payload.json \
  https://api.github.com/repos/iBug/iBug-source/git/commits
```

See the response (truncated):

```js
{
  "sha": "36105785c8665a400226c54a16cc4583b8f28ebd",
  // Truncated
}
```

See [the commit](https://github.com/iBug/iBug-source/commit/36105785c8665a400226c54a16cc4583b8f28ebd) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201116160759/https://github.com/iBug/iBug-source/commit/36105785c8665a400226c54a16cc4583b8f28ebd)) on GitHub website in action!

> [image]

---

Obviously, all the above steps can be done with your favorite toolchain, and you don't even have to perform the `git commit`. For example, the manually-constructed Git object is as follows, without the trailing newline:

```
tree fe9d12667f47065738ebcb3f6dd665a4150be267
parent fb4c5fb11f79142fc1f6f86fd7442274839626fb
author iBug <git@ibugone.com> 1605466279 +0800
committer iBug <git@ibugone.com> 1605466626 +0800
gpgsig -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
 
 iQIzBAEBAgAdFiEE1KqdrSj5MOe58w687j9yiKLGMwQFAl+ynVQACgkQ7j9yiKLG
 MwR21BAAp3pzyUhA2/5tn/DrO+bbD9X9BQ6GHLHtiaG8gjuWmaGHzjR2XUugTrRl
 aOluWR6//yNR9Uf3qIyxZahRYWYVy3Pl2UK8C+4s4alo7IjiF/7oKD3OVu5bjLvm
 GcbUfeyJQtOkNNH5o0o/einIoqhNCNgiFWjjsLcxPsG2bsNnF5Kmb8ONS3gArJQB
 7wT68sdj/oH82zCJU6bgEXohv3f+ZS82e8jX5jJBRL+ljz3crUl3DsgjsoKJiiUp
 ZjcfNffNQu4wEB6XK2zca5IgGfcBO3MF0yA13sh1JwKa54ZEikAI4T5lVfRkjUn7
 LPkwpMhw3033NyyrTFXF48i9oRSoMocJYmDOncY8Mgc+CJArvn/fT34bZ9rXH01Y
 qpeSAZv7AgyXc3jSQHZPjo76i/C9BwwZ1EoGUm4svom/0ejnOteM1Ff3grVnqipX
 Xo78a1BYHr0aLBxPpPaHMRlOdcMo0UYnqIm+P7VXtY0WxvPjXgemtSsXYrAMKSaa
 sAJ5Dv0jqYwhbQcVb5sGLC8zg+QmSbhV4HbrXmOcP8QC9H89EJSPzLQivQePGZrQ
 284vWTueNk68NyUQ5BUfXLIjYX/n6kgOeISNcvhDCVgWkvZNfN57fEOtq2FTsFKz
 Dg4ukCQkabA+lFB3AiVdhhLZT5ucjSFFfnLUkwaULRP5XEgQhH8=
 =YxhM
 -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
 

Force redirect
```

Using `git hash-object -t commit` on the file, the same commit SHA is reproduced.

Now trying to store this crafted commit object into Git database.

Prepend with the object type header:

```sh
~/iBug-source $ printf 'commit %s\0' $(wc -c < commit) | cat - commit > object
```

Get the hash of the complete object:

```sh
~/iBug-source $ sha1sum object
36105785c8665a400226c54a16cc4583b8f28ebd
```

Create directory for the object:

```sh
~/iBug-source $ mkdir -p .git/objects/36/
```

Compress the object using zlib (`.zz`) algorithm and save the object:

```sh
~/iBug-source $ pigz -cz object > .git/objects/36/105785c8665a400226c54a16cc4583b8f28ebd
```

Try if Git recognized this crafted object:

```sh
~/iBug-source $ git log -1 36105785c8665a400226c54a16cc4583b8f28ebd
commit 36105785c8665a400226c54a16cc4583b8f28ebd
Author: iBug <git@ibugone.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 16 02:51:19 2020 +0800

    Force redirect
```