# overview list - most used git commands

Tags: git, list, command

Does anyone has a short list with most used git commands? Not the complete manual, but only what I approximately need daily. I'm new and would like a small list to put under my screen. This to pickup git faster.

That's all folks!

Comment: That would be mainly the porcelain commands (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309), listed in http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html#_high_level_commands_porcelain

Comment: Thanks VonC. Not verybody likes my question, but I like your answer. I'll make a summary page myself of your link.

Comment: Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) will propose a more helpful `git help`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30699445/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with. I have printed this out, and it helps me getting started with git commands:

```
git init
git status
git log --summary

git add file.txt
git add '*.txt'     : add all files, also in subfolders
git rm file.txt     : remove file
git rm -r foldername: remove file and folders recursively

git commit -m "Descriptive text of the change"

git remote add origin https://github.com/try-git/try_git.git
git push -u origin master
git pull origin master
git diff --staged

git add folder/file.txt         : Add file to staged area
git reset folder/file.txt       : Remove file from staged area
git checkout -- folder/file.txt : checkout the last know version, restore.
git branch feature      : create branch
git checkout feature    : use branch (and do the work)
git checkout master     : go back to master before merge
git merge feature       : merge branch into master
git branch -d feature   : delete that branch that is not used any more
```

Comment: something I seem to be doing all the time:

git fetch origin [newbranch]:[newbranch] 
followed by, after I checkout the branch and try to pull,
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/[newbranch] [newbranch]

Answer (score 2):

Note: Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) will present the common Git commands in a more helpful format.

See [commit 2241477](https://github.com/git/git/commit/224147704a3696d396dae005c280f7a25de407c7) by [Sébastien Guimmara (`Groutcho`)](https://github.com/Groutcho), 21 May 2015.
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6dec263](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dec263333417738528089834bd8cda72017aa31), 01 Jun 2015)</sup>
Helped-by: Eric Sunshine

> ### `help`: respect new common command grouping
>
> '`git help`' shows common commands in alphabetical order:

```
The most commonly used git commands are:
   add        Add file contents to the index
   bisect     Find by binary search the change that introduced a bug
   branch     List, create, or delete branches
   checkout   Checkout a branch or paths to the working tree
   clone      Clone a repository into a new directory
   commit     Record changes to the repository
   [...]
```

> without any indication of how commands relate to high-level
>   concepts or each other.

**Revise the output to explain their relationship with the typical Git workflow**:

```
  These are common Git commands used in various situations:

  start a working area (see also: git help tutorial)
     clone      Clone a repository into a new directory
     init       Create an empty Git repository or reinitialize [...]

  work on the current change (see also: git help everyday)
     add        Add file contents to the index
     reset      Reset current HEAD to the specified state

  examine the history and state (see also: git help revisions)
     log        Show commit logs
     status     Show the working tree status

     [...]
```

---

With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), the completion allows to customize the completable command list.

> By default we show porcelain, external commands and a couple others
>   that are also popular. If you are not happy with this list, you can
>   now customize it a new config variable.

See [commit 6532f37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6532f3740b1c228c0a2a03a4126f4f7e4f2d73e7) and [commit 3301d36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3301d36b29467a05107340e4d9688ebf74335021) (20 May 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).

> ### `completion`: add and use `--list-cmds=alias`
>
> By providing aliases via `--list-cmds=`, we could simplify command
>   collection code in the script. We only issue one git command.
>   Before this patch that is "`git config`", after it's "`git --list-cmds=`".
>   In "`git help`" completion case we actually reduce one "`git`" process (for
>   getting guides) but that call was added in this series so it does not
>   really count.
>
> There is a slight (good) change in `_git_help()` with this patch: before
>   "`git help <tab>`" shows external commands (as in *not* part of git) as
>   well as part of `$__git_all_commands`.
>   We have finer control over command listing now and can exclude that because we can't provide a man page for external commands anyway.

You now have [the new setting](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6532f3740b1c228c0a2a03a4126f4f7e4f2d73e7/Documentation/config.txt#L1346-L1352):

> ```
> completion.commands
> ```
>
> This is only used by `git-completion.bash` to add or remove commands from the list of completed commands. Normally only porcelain commands and a few select others are completed.
>   You can add more commands, separated by space, in this variable.
>   Prefixing the command with '`-`' will remove it from the existing list.

Example:

```
git --list-cmds=list-mainporcelain,others,nohelpers,alias,list-complete,config
```

Comment: lol git help lists sparse-checkout as a commonly used command... what would really help is a most commonly forgotten commands list, not a most used command

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be doing this all the time while synchronizing branches on different computers:

`git fetch origin [newbranch]:[newbranch]`

followed by, after checking out the branch and trying to pull,

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/[newbranch] [newbranch]`

Answer (score 0):

-To view branch you working on, globally origin(local machine) and main(github server):
**git branch**

-To make sure all things are up to date before commit changes:
**git pull origin main**

-To upload everything in current project
**git add .**
**git commit -am "message to commit"**
**git push origin main**

You could check all other commands on website **https://docs.github.com/en**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).