# problems with git hub local repo --invalid key errors

Tags: git, github

I have tried to create a local directory and then initialize it (git init) as well as created one on my github account and then clone it using (git remote add origin remote_repository_url) but regardless of what I do, once I try to use any git command while in my local repo, I get the following error:
I haven't used git for the past few months but I have never encountered an error like this before. How do I fix this? [Does this have anything to do with Mavericks?)

---

error: invalid key: pager.dif$
error: invalid key: alias.dif$
git: 'dif$' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?

### diff

Comment: Could you simply clone the GitHub repo?

Comment: Did you previously edit some aliases here and there relating to pager.dif? something like this: http://oli.jp/2012/git-powerup/ (if you try on another computer is this issue reproducible with your cloned repo?)

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread: [List Git aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066325/list-git-aliases) to find out if you have defined some git-aliases.

If not, check if you have defined some aliases about `dif` in bash:

```
alias | grep dif
```

Then, to be more generally, check all aliases about git:

```
alias | grep git
```

Hope you will find something.

Comment: thank you @VonC and @ Shuai Liu. I tried the suggestions above but the error will not go away. Strangely enough, I am able to push locally added files to my github repo.