# Git - Removing or editing an alias

Tags: git, terminal, alias

I was looking for a way to edit or remove an alias in `git`. I found a solution to get every alias using [listing every alias in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066325/list-git-aliases). Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

To remove an alias, use `unset`

```
git config --global --unset alias.trololo
```

Then to edit it, simply add it again

```
git config --global alias.trololo checkout
```

Or you can simply edit the `.gitconfig` file

Source

https://github.com/githubtraining/zzz_deprecated-feedback/issues/24