# Git status: Show total changes per folder

Tags: git, bash

I am working on a project where there are VERY many changes/deletes/additions in every commit, and I am wondering if there is a way to "collapse" those changes when calling `git status`. So instead of getting a very long list along the lines of the example below:

```
deleted:    UnityMainApp/Library/metadata/ff/ffcfeb6024f134f73b27fbdd351195a6
deleted:    UnityMainApp/Library/shadercompiler-UnityShaderCompiler5.log
deleted:    UnityMainApp/Library/shadercompiler-UnityShaderCompiler6.log
deleted:    UnityMainApp/Library/shadercompiler-UnityShaderCompiler7.log
modified:   UnityMainApp/QCAR/somedata16
deleted:    UnityMainApp/UnityMainApp.sln
deleted:    UnityMainApp/UnityMainApp.userprefs
```

I would love to display the information as:

```
1 deleted in:     UnityMainApp/Library/metadata/ff
3 deleted in:     UnityMainApp/Library
1 modified in:    UnityMainApp/QCAR
2 deleted in:     UnityMainApp/
```

I looked around everywhere and could not find an answer. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git status - is there a way to show changes only in a specific directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715321/git-status-is-there-a-way-to-show-changes-only-in-a-specific-directory) One simple search with google. Why are all people incapable of performing the easiest stuff...

Comment: @ckruczek No it's not a duplicate of this.

Comment: @kennytm: What he wants is just a more specialized form of what I have linked. Further work, like putting a script around it needs to be done...come one guys this is not a ice-cream shop. Furthermore, it is just a **possible** duplicate.

Comment: @ckruczek No read OP's question and your linked question carefully. OP wants a *count of changed files in every subdirectory*.

Comment: I was asking if there was any common or built in ways of doing this without having to write any scripts. And yes @kennytm that is what I am asking. If no-one knows of a way to do it I guess ill eventually write a little helper script and put it up somewhere.